# how can I prevent an Error on the delete rule deny in Core Data, Swift 3

Tags: core-data, swift3

how can I prevent an Error on the delete rule deny? I have a Alert that ask the user for deletion a record, but the check if it can be deleted happens first in the save method in core data stack. I trieb to catch it with:

```
if (self?.categoryToEdit.toMyplace == nil){
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Kategorie löschen", message: "Die Kategorie " + categoryName + " kann nicht gelöscht werden!\r\nSie ist ", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel, handler: { [weak self](action) -> Void in
            self?.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
            self?.attemptFetch()
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
            return
        })
        alertController.addAction(cancelButton)
        self?.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }else{
        self?.displayActionSheet(indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
    }
```

so I get an error from compiler: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance!!!!

**EDIT**

Thank you!
Here the complete code.
It starts in the tableView action and is forwarded to separate function where the alerts are handled. The uncommented parts in this functions are not really working. I get first an alert when it handles the error.
It wouldn't be a huge Problem if the record didn't vanish from the tableView and left incense in the index of the working array.
This problem remains till the App will be restarted there are noch chance to get the not deleted record. I try new fetch requests and reloaded the table date but it stays away till new start.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Ändern") { [weak self] action, index in
        self?.editMode = true
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CategoryTVCell
        self?.configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        context.performAndWait{
            if let obj = self?.controller.fetchedObjects , obj.count > 0 {
                self?.categoryToEdit = obj[indexPath.row]
                self?.categoryToEditName = self?.categoryToEdit.name!
            }
        }
        self?.showAlertWithText()
        self?.showAlertWithText()
        tableView.isEditing = false
    }

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Löschen") { [weak self] action, index in
        self?.displayActionSheet(indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 179.0/255.0, green: 179.0/255.0, blue: 179.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    delete.backgroundColor = myRedAlertColor
    return [delete, edit]
}
private func displayActionSheet(indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{   let categoryName = categoryArray[indexPath.row]
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Kategorie löschen", message: "Soll die Kategorie " + categoryName + " gelöscht werden?\r\nDie Kategorie kann nur gelöscht werden, wenn kein myPlace damit verbunden ist!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let deleteCategory = UIAlertAction(title: "Löschen", style: .destructive, handler: { [weak self](action) -> Void in
        self?.tableView.isEditing = false
        //if (self?.categoryToEdit.toMyplace == nil)/*((self?.myPlace?.toCateogry == nil))*/{
            context.delete((self?.controller.fetchedObjects?[indexPath.row])!)
            self?.categoryArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self?.attemptFetch()
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        //}else{
            /*let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Kategorie löschen", message: "Die Kategorie " + categoryName + " kann nicht gelöscht werden!\r\nSie ist ", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel, handler: { [weak self](action) -> Void in
                self?.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
                self?.attemptFetch()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            alertController.addAction(cancelButton)
            self?.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)*/
        //}
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Kategorie löschen", message: "Die Kategorie " + categoryName + " kann nicht gelöscht werden!\r\nAlle myPlaces verlieren sonst diese Zuordnung!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel, handler: { [weak self](action) -> Void in
                self?.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
                self?.attemptFetch()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            alertController.addAction(cancelButton)
            self?.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)

        }
    })

    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel, handler: { [weak self](action) -> Void in
        self?.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    })

    alertController.addAction(deleteCategory)
    alertController.addAction(cancelButton)
    alertController.view.tintColor = .orange //UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 51)
    //self.navigationController!.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code that does the delete. Also what does your core data stack look like?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
Here the complete code.
It starts in the tableView action and is forwarded to separate function where the alerts are handled. The uncommented parts in this functions are not really working. I get first an alert when it handles the error.
It wouldn't be a huge Problem if the record didn't vanish from the tableView and left incense in the index of the working array.
This problem remains till the App will be restarted there are noch chance to get the not deleted record. I try new fetch requests and reloaded the table date but it stays away till new start.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Ändern") { [weak self] action, index in
        self?.editMode = true
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CategoryTVCell
        self?.configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        context.performAndWait{
            if let obj = self?.controller.fetchedObjects , obj.count > 0 {
                self?.categoryToEdit = obj[indexPath.row]
                self?.categoryToEditName = self?.categoryToEdit.name!
            }
        }
        self?.showAlertWithText()
        self?.showAlertWithText()
        tableView.isEditing = false
    }

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Löschen") { [weak self] action, index in
        self?.displayActionSheet(indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 179.0/255.0, green: 179.0/255.0, blue: 179.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    delete.backgroundColor = myRedAlertColor
    return [delete, edit]
}
private func displayActionSheet(indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{   let categoryName = categoryArray[indexPath.row]
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Kategorie löschen", message: "Soll die Kategorie " + categoryName + " gelöscht werden?\r\nDie Kategorie kann nur gelöscht werden, wenn kein myPlace damit verbunden ist!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let deleteCategory = UIAlertAction(title: "Löschen", style: .destructive, handler: { [weak self](action) -> Void in
        self?.tableView.isEditing = false
        //if (self?.categoryToEdit.toMyplace == nil)/*((self?.myPlace?.toCateogry == nil))*/{
            context.delete((self?.controller.fetchedObjects?[indexPath.row])!)
            self?.categoryArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self?.attemptFetch()
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        //}else{
            /*let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Kategorie löschen", message: "Die Kategorie " + categoryName + " kann nicht gelöscht werden!\r\nSie ist ", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel, handler: { [weak self](action) -> Void in
                self?.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
                self?.attemptFetch()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            alertController.addAction(cancelButton)
            self?.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)*/
        //}
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Kategorie löschen", message: "Die Kategorie " + categoryName + " kann nicht gelöscht werden!\r\nAlle myPlaces verlieren sonst diese Zuordnung!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel, handler: { [weak self](action) -> Void in
                self?.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
                self?.attemptFetch()
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            })
            alertController.addAction(cancelButton)
            self?.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)

        }
    })

    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel, handler: { [weak self](action) -> Void in
        self?.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    })

    alertController.addAction(deleteCategory)
    alertController.addAction(cancelButton)
    alertController.view.tintColor = .orange //UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 51)
    //self.navigationController!.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: please remove this post, as this is the update in question, i have merged this update into question.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution:

```
let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Löschen") 
{ 
   [weak self] action, index in

    do{
          try self?.controller.fetchedObjects?[indexPath.row].validateForDelete()
          self?.displayActionSheet(indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
       }catch{
          let categoryName = self?.categoryArray[indexPath.row]
          let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Kategorie löschen", message: "Die Kategorie " + categoryName! + " kann nicht gelöscht werden!\r\nSie wird bereits verwendet!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
          let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", 
                                           style: .cancel, handler: { 

                        [weak self](action) -> Void in
                        self?.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
                        self?.attemptFetch()
                        self?.tableView.reloadData()
            })

          alertController.addAction(cancelButton)
          self?.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
      }
}
```

It was simply the function .validateForDelete()